# SQL query choose row for many fields

Tags: sql

I have a DB which has 2 columns.

```
PostTown | PostCode
```

I have 100 unique PostTown for every PostTown I have thousands of PostCode

What I want to do is say:

```
select distinct(PostTown), first(PostCode) from PostData
```

So I just want the first PostCode for the PostTown, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS?  And which first -- based on what criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define "first", but here is a good approach:

```
select postTown, min(PostCode)
from PostData
group by postTown
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having a field to Order By, I'm not sure you can guarantee getting the first record.  You could try something like this using the Row_Number:

SQL Server/Oracle:

```
select
    PostTown, 
    PostCode
from
    (
    select 
        PostTown, 
        PostCode, 
        Row_Number() OVER (Partition By PostTown ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
    from PostData
    ) t
where rn = 1
```

MySQL:

```
select
    PostTown, 
    PostCode
from
    (
    select 
        @rn:=IF(@PrevPostTown=PostTown,@rn+1,1) rn,
        PostTown, 
        PostCode, 
        @PrevPostTown:=PostTown
    from PostData
    order by PostTown
    ) t
where rn = 1
```

@GordonLinoff provides a great way to always get the Minimum PostCode as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the first PostCode from each PostTown, AND you have an auto-incrementing id column, try this:

```
SELECT 
    PostTown,
    PostCode,
FROM SomeTable sta
WHERE sta.id = (SELECT MIN(id) from SomeTable WHERE PostTown = sta.PostTown)
```

It's a weird construct, and I don't know how efficient it is, but it got me a reliable primary image when I had multiple images per product to deal with.